# I need help in this Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$myStr = "Since its 1990 launch, Hubble has changed our fundamental understanding of the universe.";
$myStr =~ s/a\wn//gi;
$myStr =~ s/an//gi;
print $myStr . "\n";
```

The result is: Since its 1990 lch, Hubble has chged our fundamental understding of the universe.

But I don't quite understand why they got that result. Could anyone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: You have a couple of good answers. But, when asking a question like this, it's always a good idea to tell us what you don't understand. What would you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very basic regex.

`\w` is special escapes which means to match word character. More info - https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes

`s///` search a string for pattern and replace it with given text. More info - https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer

So in line -

```
$myStr =~ s/a\wn//gi;
```

you are saying 'search for a string containing `'a', any word character and 'n'` respectively and replace it with empty (null)'.

`i` is for ignore case. So it will look at both uppercase and lowercase char.

In next line -

```
$myStr =~ s/an//gi;
```

you are saying - 'search for `'a' and 'n'` and replace it with empty(null)'

So this is exactly what is happening. In your `$myStr`

1. Wherever there is continuous 'a', and word and 'n' after that that is removed. (as in 'l**aun**ch')
2. or continuous 'a' and 'n' is removed (as in ch**an**ged and underst**an**ding )

Please have a  look at [perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) for more details.

You can also checkout https://regex101.com/ for more understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myStr =~ s/a\wn//gi;
```

Replaces all occurences of `a`or `A`, followed by one word character, followed by `n` or `N` with the empty string.

```
$myStr =~ s/an//gi;
```

Replaces all occurences of `a`or `A`, followed by `n` or `N` with the empty string.

See [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) for documentation od the substitution operator `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`.

See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for an introduction into perl regular expressions.